# Logging out then Logging in as different user is showing previous user info and overriding current user data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Beyond stumped on how this is happening. I know a codepin would be optimal but I have so many files going on that it would be tricky, will do if it comes to that point. If you think by viewing the page and trying for yourself then I can send the link.

**Setup**
AngularJS/Angular Material, Firebase Hosting, Firebase Auth, Firebase Database
**Site**

3 pages:
• Login/Signup
• Profile
• Edit Profile

All working fine and dandy, storing/updating info into Firebase great.

**Issue**
• Login as user A, see profile A info, edit if needed, whatever, all fine.
• Click Log Out, runs firebase.auth().signOut(), takes you back to Login page, log shows no user signed in
• Login as user B, see profile A info and database info has instantly been overridden from profile B info to profile A. **Blowing my mind.**

Data can only be saved in one spot in Edit Profile page when Save is clicked ( runs saveData() ).

 
But somehow after logging in as user B and moving to the Profile page, saveData() from Edit Profile page is firing?? They are completely different controllers with different functions.

**EDIT:** Also note, Login/Profile/Edit Profile are loaded into ng-view via $routeProvider in case that helps.

**EDIT 2:** I have console.log set in both controllers (Profile/ProfileEdit) and also console.log when they get firebase info. But here is the log when this error occurs:
ProfileCtrl entered   app.js:242 
ProfileCtrl signed into Firebase   app.js:247 
ProfileEditCtrl signed into Firebase   app.js:305 
ProfileCtrl signed into Firebase   app.js:247

"ProfileEditCtrl signed into Firebase" should not be happening, it is a completely different controller and that view is not being loaded.

Comment: does this happen from two different browsers or incognito mode?  i imagine it doesn't meaning you aren't clearing all your variables on logout, including clearing cookies or local datastore if you are using that.

Comment: @abc123 I basically only use Chrome Private mode when testing this, but also pulled up Firefox which has never even been on the site.. Logged in as A, logged out, Logged in as B, stuff overridden. I know it would be a rare instance that someone would even do that(or maybe never), but still something that should get fixed without clearing cache.

Comment: Ok just found the exact scenario it happens.. Works fine here: Log in as A, Profile A, Log out, Log in as B, Profile B. BUT When you edit one: Log in as A, Profile A, Edit A, Log Out, Log in as B, Profile A, then boom. There's an error on the Edit Profile controller, which shouldn't even be loaded?

Comment: Right, because you aren't clearing the variables of your single page application and or the cookies...you are getting the old values from the previous user...  i was saying log into A with chrome then logout, then log into B with firefox...you won't have the issue.

Comment: Chris, when you open the edit controller...it is setting some variables, make sure that on logout these variables are cleared, to help further...include your code in the question

Comment: @abc123 Ok I will try to clear the variables. Even so, I understand them loading the variables when the Profile shows, but how is it setting them in Firebase without saveData() ever being clicked?

Comment: Chris, I don't have your code so these are just educated guesses...my assumption would be this...When edit is clicked all variables are assigned, when login is called for Profile B it still has Profile A database id, but the other variables are still the previous variables.  so it displays the wrong things but doesn't set them in the DB just visually, when you click edit, it saves the changes (if you click save).  To prove this cause the issue in one browser, don't click save.  Open second browser log into profile B, see if the data wasn't changed in the DB.

Comment: Thats the thing, I never even click edit or get to save. I only Log in as B and once the Profile Page loads it has A info, Firebase instantly updates even though Edit Profile view didn't even load for B. Here is the link if that helps, thanks a lot for all the help. https://beam-995b9.firebaseapp.com/